# Pip not installing windows 10

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip

I am having trouble installing pip. I downloaded the latest version of python (3.8.5) and then i got the get-pip.py file and saved it in my documents folder. After that I went into the command prompt to the documents folder and type "python get-pip.py" as well as "py get-pip.py" and nothing happened. According to the tutorials that I watched, I should've seen a progress bar and some other technical information. I installed this on my Mac machine a while back and was able to do this easily.

Comment: Couple of questions:
Have you tried running pip on the cmd and if so what error did yoy get?
Have you tried running python get-pip.py as admin?

Comment: I have tried running pip on the cmd line and get an error saying that it is not recognized. I tried running as admin and get the same thing. All it does once I press enter is it returns a blank line and the a new cmd line

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path of the pip install to your PATH system variable via Control Panel or by using the `setx` command

Generally it is installed to `C:\Python38\Scripts\pip` by default.

If you are unsure of whether or not it is in your path you can type  `echo %path%`  into a CMD prompt.

Comment: I did that but python is not installed in that location, should I change the path variable to wherever I have python and subsequently pip, installed? I would like python to be installed in an intuitive location and currently it is buried in my user directory under start menu programs, can I just move it to a new location?

Comment: So I uninstalled the current version of python and reinstalled it in a new location and I clicked advanced installation and I picked an easy location. Also I noted that pip is supposed to come with my download. The installation wizard showed that pip is by default installed yet when I open the scripts folder it isn't there.

Comment: Looks like you solved your problem already, but yes the path should be the location where it is installed for you.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this, all I did was install python in an easy to access location. Before ot was under users\appdata..... and a bunch of other useless locations. Then I made sure pip was clicked in the installation wizard. I also had to add it to the path myself. For that I went to control panel -> System and Security -> System -> advanced system settings (left hand menu) ->environment variables (button at bottom of first screen) -> under system variables scroll until you find path then double click or select and click edit -> click new -> type in path to file